# Eloquent Delete - SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '808498e7-a393-42f1-ab23-6ee89eb7040a'
```

When trying to delete records through a relationship, using:

```
$delivery->stockMovements()->delete();
```

The raw query shows as:

```
delete from `stock_movements` where `stock_movements`.`entity_id` = 10000005 and `stock_movements`.`entity_id` is not null and `stock_movements`.`company_id` = 8b11050c-612c-4922-8b34-d04d579e02a9
```

I have searched and searched but cannot find anything specific to this other than it may be something to do with a cast error. Maybe something to do with UUID's?

Migrations as follows:

```
    Schema::create('deliveries', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->uuid('company_id');
        $table->string('delivery_type');
        $table->string('supplier_name');
        $table->string('supplier_ref')->nullable();
        $table->string('merchant_ref')->nullable();
        $table->string('carrier_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('status');
        $table->date('expected_delivery');
        $table->dateTime('completed_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });


    Schema::create('stock_movements', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->uuid('company_id');
        $table->uuid('product_id');
        $table->string('entity_type'); //can be order / delivery
        $table->string('entity_id'); //can be UUID / String / Integer
        $table->string('location_id')->nullable(); // can be warehouse_location / shipment_package / delivery_container
        $table->string('action')->default('');
        $table->integer('qty')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I know it's several months old, but since there is no accepted solution I'm posting mine.
I had the exact same error message but in a slightly different context:

```
Table::whereIn('fk_id', $arrayOfFkIds)
                ->delete();
```

The array contained values that were either strings (like 'ABC1234', like your company_id) or integers.

The workaround was when I build this array, I cast everything to string:

```
$arrayOfFkIds[] = (string)$parsedArray['stuff_id'];
```

Then no more SQL error, everything works smoothly.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are missing quotes, so that your UUID can be seen as a string type:

```
delete from `stock_movements` where `stock_movements`.`entity_id` = 10000005 and `stock_movements`.`entity_id` is not null and `stock_movements`.`company_id` = '8b11050c-612c-4922-8b34-d04d579e02a9'
```

The value of `company_id` is seen as a number/double (in any case not as a string), so you might have forgotten to turn it into a string before you put it into the query.

Answer (score 2):

This error message can also occur if the variable you are comparing has no value.

For example: `$id = ''` and `User::where('id', $id)`.

I came across this question when searching for solution to same error in my code, i  noticed the variable am working on has no value and the error was resolved and code  working fine when the variable start getting appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

This what I got

SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 's'

in my case the issue was the type of category columns is Int(11) and in WHERE I used string instead of number then it return that error, I used PDO with prepared and no datetime in the database so this error not related to datetime in my case.

solved when make `WHERE category = 1`

Answer (score -1):

I have just run into the exact same issue, when trying to delete Models through an Eloquent scope.

This results in the exact same error as abovementioned:

```php
return $query->whereNotIn('remote_status', $this->typeDeletedStatuses)
```

The solution of type casting was too brittle for my taste, not obvious enough.
So after some trial and error I separated the `int` and `string` statuses, and rebuilt the query like so:

```php
return $query->whereNotIn('remote_status', $this->typeDeletedStatuses)
            ->orWhereIntegerNotInRaw('remote_status', $this->typeIntDeletedStatuses);
```

Now the scope works as expected.