# PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE : value when I try to delete something from mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I promise I have read all the questions with this title however I cannot find a solution for my problem

in this code I want to show users from my database

```
                for($i = 0;$i<count($users);$i++){
                    echo '<tr class = "data-row">' ;
                        echo '<td class="data-left-side">' . $users[$i]["id"] . '</td>' ;
                        echo '<td class="data-pet-name">' . $users[$i]["nameSurname"] . '</td>' ;
                        echo '<td class="data-user-name">' . $users[$i]["petName"] . '</td>' ;
                        echo '<td class="action-right-side">' ;
                            echo '<a class="delete-btn" href="?delete=' . $users[$i]["id"] .' title="Delete"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can fa-xl"></i></a>'; 
                            echo ' <a class="edit-btn" href="edit.php?id=' . $users[$i]["id"] . ' title="Edit"><i class="fa-solid fa-pen fa-xl"></i></i></a>' ;
                        echo '</td>' ;
                    echo '</tr>' ;
                }
                ?>
```

in that part I have some another php codes for deleting row from database

```
if ( isset($_GET["delete"])) {
       $id = $_GET["delete"] ;
       $user = getUser($id) ;
       try {
          $stmt = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM users where id = ? ") ;
          $stmt->execute([$id]) ;
          $msg = "{$user["nameSurname"]} Silindi" ;
          header("Location: index.php") ;
       } catch(PDOException $ex) {
            $ex->getMessage();
            echo $ex ;
       } 
   }
```

and I can assure that except deleting everything works well eg: editing or inserting new users. However when I try to deleting something it gives me **PDOException: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:** this error message

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What value is being passed for `$id` in the deletion code, and what is the column type of `id` in the database? The answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53683774/eloquent-delete-sqlstate22007-invalid-datetime-format-1292-truncated-incor may possibly be helpful to you.

Comment: int type of users id is passed by $id I have read this question however it wont help and I am not using any date time value in my database table

Comment: Neither was the person who asked the question. And the solution had nothing to do with dates either. The error message doesn't entirely make sense.

Comment: I solved the problem I have missed the double quotation echos after ```$users[$i]["id"]```  thats why I send ```title="Delete" ``` part also thx for your helping :)